# add an icon under the submit button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, struts2

hello guys i'm using bootstrap and struts 2
and I would like to add icon under the submit button.

my code is

```
<s:submit type="button" cssClass="btn btn-primary" method="editer" key="Modifier" theme="simple"><i class="icon-ok"></i></s:submit>
```

it show me the icon in front of the submit button

how can i do it ?

Comment: title- "add an icon in front of the text in the submit button", description -"I would like to add icon under the submit button".

Comment: yes i'm sorry it was an error i have edited the title :)

Comment: What do you mean by "under the submit button" because it is *under the submit button*.

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<br>` tag in front of the icon as follows:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" method="editer" key="Modifier" theme="simple"><br><i class="icon-ok"></i></input>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------here ^
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3WAYH/1/)

Comment: Well it's working in the demo as per the code you provided. if it does not work it has something to do with your code. please provide sufficient code to reproduce the issue or a minimal demo where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

use `theme='simple'` for Bootstrap.

```
 <s:submit type="button" cssClass="btn btn-primary" method="editer" key="Modifier" ><i class="icon-ok" theme="simple">Submit</i></s:submit>
```